# Distributed GNU Make for Win32

Tags: winapi, build-process, makefile

Is there a version of GNU Make, or GNU Make compatible application, which supports distributed builds on Win32?

We currently have a large project using gnu makefiles.  We use the Win32 version of GMake to build.  Our build environment supports parallel builds without a problem, and we'd like to try and perform a distributed build if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`distcc`](http://distcc.samba.org/) is the grand-father of doing this, though I'm not sure it would be easy to get running on win32. [`cygwin`](http://www.cygwin.com/) might make this possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) but the performance might be poor because of the emulation layer.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I've understood Your problem properely, but
You can use:

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)
or
[mingw](http://www.mingw.org/)

MinGw is a complete port of GNU binutils for windows.

Answer (score 0):

ElectricAccelerator from Electric Cloud does exactly this.  It's a parallel, distributed replacement for gmake and nmake.  If your build problem is bad enough and you have some budget to spend on a solution, you should check it out:

[ElectricAccelerator home page](http://www.electric-cloud.com/products/electricaccelerator.php)

Disclaimer:  I'm the tech lead for the Accelerator team at Electric Cloud.